# Nextjs with redux redux-saga initialize store

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga, next.js

js like this

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import nextReduxSaga from 'next-redux-saga'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'

import {initialState} from './initialState'
import globalSaga from '../sagas/global'

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

export function configureStore (reducers,initialState) {
  console.log(initialState)

  let states = {}
  Object.keys(reducers).map((key) => {
    states[key] = initialState[key]
  })

  console.log(reducers)
  console.log(states)
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({reducers}),
    states,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
  )
  store.sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(globalSaga)
  return store
}

export function withReduxSaga (BaseComponent, reducers) {
  return withRedux(configureStore(reducers,initialState))(nextReduxSaga(BaseComponent))
}

export default function configureWithReduxSaga(component,reducers){
  return withReduxSaga(component,reducers)
}
```

and the error is

```
Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to

makeStore is not a function
```

What might be wrong, basically I would like to write function that adds **reducers** and **store.global** with specific sagas into nextjs component without much code, best would be something like this:

```
configureWithReduxSaga(
{reducer1, reducer2},
{saga1, saga2}
)
```

is it possible? I can create root reducer and root saga and pass it to every component, that is not hard to code, but is it performant?

Comment: So is it resolved? I have the same issue but i can't understand nothing from answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
combineReducers({reducers}),
```

Most likely that you have dictionary of reducers, but provide them wrapped into redundant object. Use rest spread operator `combineReducers({...reducers})` or simple object passing `combineReducers(reducers)` in that case. See original documentation for it: https://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html#arguments

If `reducers` is array, you should iterate over it and give own name to each reducer.